# Get variable mode development or production in webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm using Webpack 4 and I want to use env environment variable in config. How I get this variable with mode --development and --production ? DefinePlugin doesn't work and documention says nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP was asking about webpack4. In webpack4 one can use `--mode` argument  which automatically sets `mode` in webpack config.

#### How to use `mode` inside webpack config?

An example way of passing `mode` to `webpack-cli`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "webpack --mode development --watch"
}
```

in webpack config you can use 2nd parameter `argv` to access arguments:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
...
   watch: argv.mode !== 'production',
...
})
```

**update**

If you use IDE that reads webpack config (e.g. Intellij IDEA) you may need to pass some default value for `argv`:

```
module.exports = (env, argv = {}) => ({
```

in order to have valid config even if IDE doesn't pass `argv`
(in my case, I needed it for a support of webpack alias module resolution in IDE).

**update2**

Another thing is babel config. Maybe it's a less known fact but babel and its presets and plugins can react on `NODE_ENV` (it's configurable as well), for example you can configure `development` option of `@babel/preset-react` (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react#development).
In order to do that you still need to set `NODE_ENV` (by default or sth else if you modified `babel.config.js`) before running webpack.

Why? The only things that `--mode` does are 1) the value is available via `argv.mode` in your config 2) sets `NODE_ENV` via `DefinePlugin` for your bundles *however* `NODE_ENV` is not set for webpack config itself nor loaders.

Finally, you can use the following if you want the consistency between bundling environment and generated bundles:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this:

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --env.NODE_ENV=development",
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env.NODE_ENV=production"
},
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    mode: env.NODE_ENV,
    // ...rest of config based on environment
  };
};
```

[more on passing environmental variables to config.](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/)